# Decent way to say "I would have gone to say XXX if you didn't mention YYY'"

Tags: conversation

I need help from a native speaker on this question A hypothetical scenario is as below:

A friend comes to you and says, "Coffee?". However, before he asked me, I was thinking of saying "Have a coffee break?" to him.

I might compose a response like the following; but are there more decent ways?

"*Oh great! I'd have asked you to have a cup of coffee if you didn't ask!*"

Answer (score 13):

I might say something along the lines of:

> I was thinking the same thing.

Or:

> I was just about to suggest the same thing.

Or (this is a bit more of an idiom):

> Great minds think alike.

Comment: You know, I was just about to ask the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Some options that are a bit more casual (i.e. best with friends, not bosses):

> You took the words right out of my mouth.
>
> It's like you read my mind.
>
> Whoa, get out of my head.
>
> Synchronicity!

Comment: +1 Note: Those are in order of obscurity :) (I've never heard the last one though I would get it if someone used it...)

Comment: I hear the last one all the time, and the first one @user is used in a great rock-anthem song in English!

Answer (score 0):

Among my family and friends (from Australia and Ireland), we would sometimes say:

> SNAP!

after [the card game of the same name](http://boardgames.about.com/od/cardgames/a/snap.htm).

In the card game, players place unknown cards down in front of each other at the same time. If the cards don't match, the players draw another card from their respective piles. If the cards match, the first to say *SNAP!* wins both piles. The aim is to win all the cards.

This is *very* idiomatic, though.

Comment: In the US, children say "Jinx!"; when I was a kid, the full phrase was "Jinx on jinx - you owe me a beer!"  Since we were seriously underage at the time, the "beer" was obviously a joke.  However, I don't think that either "SNAP!" or "Jinx!" fits the OP's situation - it's not that both people say something at the same time, but that the other person suggests something that you yourself were thinking of at the moment (such as coffee.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matthew Burr - this is the perfect occasion to use ["Great minds think alike"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+minds+think+alike):

> "You know what? Great minds think
>   alike! I was just thinking of having
>   coffee now that you've mentioned it"

see this [note](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Great+minds+think+alike):

> Prov. Very intelligent people tend to
>   come up with the same ideas at the
>   same time. (Used playfully, to commend
>   someone for expressing the same thing
>   you were thinking of; implies that you
>   are congratulating that person for
>   being as smart as you are. Also **Great
>   minds run in the same gutters**, a
>   casual and jocular variant.)